# how do I verify reCAPTCHA with javascript?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm fairly new to javascript but I'm trying to use google's reCAPTCHA. So I'm able to render the reCAPTCHA but unable to make my form submit button to be disabled when the reCAPTCHA hasn't verified the person using the form is a human. Currently I have the below script added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
          'sitekey' : 'my_site_key'
        });
    };
    var wait = function() {
        if(grecaptcha.getResponse() != '') {
            alert("is it working?");
            document.getElementById("submit_button").disabled = 'disabled';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `callback` to the render parameter:

```
var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
      'callback' : 'correctCaptcha'
    });
  };

var correctCaptcha = function(response) {
    alert(response);
};
```